# How to select more than 20 rows in SPHINX engine?

Tags: mariadb, sphinx

I use [SphinxSE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sphinx-storage-engine/) instead of `FULLTEXT`. Sphinx settings are for end-users of a search engine. According to the official [documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html),

> LIMIT clause. Both LIMIT N and LIMIT M,N forms are supported. Unlike
> in regular SQL (but like in Sphinx API), an implicit LIMIT 0,20 is
> present by default.

Therefore, any query returns only 20 rows

```
MariaDB [sphinx]> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE query='test;mode=any';
+------+--------+---------------+
| id   | weight | query         |
+------+--------+---------------+
|  556 |      1 | test;mode=any |
|  864 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 1329 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 1781 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 1832 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 2157 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 2388 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 2889 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 3118 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 3155 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 3255 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 3485 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 3495 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 3623 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 4034 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 4525 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 4563 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 4659 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 4736 |      1 | test;mode=any |
| 4807 |      1 | test;mode=any |
+------+--------+---------------+
20 rows in set (0.027 sec)
```

I experimented with various settings in the `sphinx.conf`, but am unable to change the setting to return more results in a SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [docs](https://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/2.2.10/sphinxse-using.html) you can include `limit=40`. So:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE query='test;mode=any;limit=40';
```

Not a usual SQL way, but SphinxSE isn't quite normal.

Comment: very silly of me, I was trying `LIMIT` in my SQL query rather than SphinxSE query.